# The light effect in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

How to implement the light effect in tailwind? Need the icon to shine.

Example (watch first icon):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVjMo.png)

Tried to make it through "box-shadow" changing the color of the shadow to white. The effect is not like i wanted: a shadow is formed on the borders of the icon.

Currently implemented via css:

```
.box-shadow-hover:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50));
 }
```

Is this possible in tailwind ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use colored Box Shadow in Tailwind CSS for NProgress Glow effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68515538/use-colored-box-shadow-in-tailwind-css-for-nprogress-glow-effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with the default configuration if you want to do it in the `tailwind` way you'll need to extend the theme adding your shadow.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow/#box-shadows

Comment: In tailwind the shadow does not interact well with the icons. Either I do something wrong. Thank you for your answer

Comment: For those 'one offs' no need to extend now although for a button you probably want to define it. Arbitrary values can now be applied inline if need be: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow#arbitrary-values

Answer (score 5):

For anyone want just quick copy here is add this to tailwind config

-> https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme

```js
extend: {
  dropShadow: {
    glow: [
      "0 0px 20px rgba(255,255, 255, 0.35)",
      "0 0px 65px rgba(255, 255,255, 0.2)"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can now use https://tailwindcss.com/docs/drop-shadow

> Use the drop-shadow-{amount} utilities alongside the filter utility to blur an element.