# Use colored Box Shadow in Tailwind CSS for NProgress Glow effect?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to make a glow effect on the progress bar near the end like https://codepen.io/brundolf/pen/YWEgLJ

[image: glow effect]

I am using [NProgress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress/). This is the CSS used to create glow effect:

```css
/* Fancy blur effect */
#nprogress .peg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #29d, 0 0 5px #29d;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
}
```

I converted it to Tailwind like:

```css
/* Fancy blur effect */
#nprogress .peg {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #29d, 0 0 5px #29d;
  @apply block absolute right-0 w-[100px] h-full opacity-100 rotate-3 translate-x-0 -translate-y-1;
}
```

But only `box-shadow` is remaining. Is there any way to convert a colored `box-shadow`?

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67569420/6141587) suggest that it can work usign `drop-shadow` & `filter`. Can it?

If so, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to reuse this later on? If not, why would you even want to convert  it to tailwind? Leave it in css.

Anyway, to make tailwind class you need to add this shadow to config, like that:

```js
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      boxShadow: {
        "nprogress": "0 0 10px #29d, 0 0 5px #29d"
      }
    }
  }
```

Use it like `shadow-nprogress` in the code.

[Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow#box-shadows)

Comment: I thought there was a way using the linked answer. There isn't. I thought `drop-shadow` & `filters` might be a solution or some CSS variable `var(--tw-shadow)` which seems more likely but Creator of Tailwind said it's in the works for [v3](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/654#issuecomment-886181037). Currently left in CSS as it's just a one-time thing :)

Answer (score 4):

Now Tailwind supports [colored box shadows](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3#colored-box-shadows) since v3.0.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="m-10 w-20 h-20 bg-gray-100 shadow-lg shadow-blue-500/50">
</div>

<div class="m-10 w-20 h-20 bg-gray-100 shadow-lg shadow-[#29d]">
</div>
```